# Scrapy not able to extract links

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a crawler to extract links and text from a webpage. This is the structure of the content

DIV
 - UL
   - LI
    - a

Here is my code

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import StackItem


class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://page.com",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        documents = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="node-329"]/div[1]/ul/li')

        for document in documents:
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = document.xpath('./a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = document.xpath('/a/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

Basically, the tag /a/@href is not working. If I comment that and try to extract only the text, it works.

Please help me.

Comment: Try using a relative XPath, ie. `document.xpath('./a/@href')`, just like you do the line before

Comment: @paultrmbrth Still nothing

Comment: Then you need to provide your input HTML

Comment: so first check `a` . maybe they don't have `href` or page use JS to add `href` to links. Or maybe you get some error message.

Comment: @paultrmbrth sorry, didnt get you

Comment: @furas it does have href. It works fine when I test it on the console using the xpath. If it helps, this is the page I am trying to extract from http://www.aipass.org/documenti%20ufficiali

Comment: In scrapy shell, in same loop as you, `{"title": doc.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first(), "link": doc.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()}` works fine

Comment: Note that you probably want absolute links, so use `response.urljoin(doc.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first())`

Comment: @paultrmbrth I got this to work in scrapy shell `response.xpath('//*[@id="node-329"]/div[1]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()` . Its showing all the hrefs. But its still not working in the script

Comment: Can you share logs from a `scrapy crawl stack`? including the stats at the end

Comment: so the only difference is you assign result to  `item['link']` - so maybe `item['link']` is the problem.

Comment: @furas Damn. That was it. Changed it to `item['url']` and it started working. Thank you so much

Comment: @kanishka weird, do you know why it didn't work with `link` but works with `url`? Could you show us your item class?